How to find the feasible solution when the value of the objective function is known?
I am a network engineer working on a network optimization problem where we are exploring the use of Machine Learning to identify the Pareto boundary in a multi-objective optimization context. Our neighboring team has successfully deployed a model that approximates the Pareto boundary with results that are practically acceptable from an engineering standpoint.
Here is an example of the model output for reference:
$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{f_1}\left( {{x_1},{x_2},...,{x_n}} \right) = 3}\\
{{f_2}\left( {{x_1},{x_2},...,{x_n}} \right) = 16}
\end{array}} \right.$
Here (3,16) are a point that the engineer team select from the Pareto boundary (The ML model spit out this point). Now, the engineer team just want to find the corresponding feasible point $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$ from the system of equation.
The challenge we face now is finding corresponding feasible solutions for these outputs $(3,16)$. While polynomial objective functions like these can technically be resolved using Groebner Bases to find all possible solutions, this method is prohibitively slow given the NP-hard nature of the ideal membership problem.
Considering the noisy nature of our input data, we are primarily interested in identifying just one feasible solution, and it does not need to be exact.
Could anyone suggest a more efficient method or approach to locate a feasible solution in scenarios like this? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.
I attach some of the recent publication on this ML technique Improving Pareto Front Learning via Multi-Sample Hypernetworks. The ML model spit out the blue point from figure 3 of the aforementioned publication.
Thank you very much for your help!

Could you give some more details on how the approximate Pareto boundary is obtained? Are the pre-images lost in the process somehow, or do you never consider those?

Well their machine learning algorithm learn the Pareto boundary. If they input some optimization data it will spit out the boundary

Is there any reason to believe a solution $x$ exists that would yield (exactly or as a close approximation) the objective values generated by the ML model?

@Sune I attach one recent publication on this technique in the main question for you

I don't see any easy way to obtain a feasible pre-image of a specific (approximate) non-dominated outcome vector - especially as there might not exist one.
One way to proceed is to add slack and surplus variables to objective constraints and then optimise the following program:
\begin{align}
\min\ & u_1+u_2-l_1-l_2\\
\text{s.t.:}\ & f_1(x)+l_1-u_1=y_1\\
\ & f_2(x)+l_2-u_2=y_2\\
\ & x\in X\\
\ & l,u\geq 0
\end{align}
where $X$ is your feasible set and $y$ is a point on your approximate frontier. This is essentially a goal program. The negative weight on the slack variables in the objective is based on the assumption that your are minimising.

Are there any solvers that allow polynomial equation constraints?

@prubin I'm fairly certain SCIP does

If an inequality is better, and you want a solution that is as little dominated by the ideal point as possible, you can change the constraints to $f_i(x) - u_i \leq y^I_i$

@Sune I am sorry but what is $l_1$, $l_2$ and $u_1$, $u_2$ used for ? I am not really understand you answer because I am an engineer and not mathematician. Forgive me but can you elaborate more clearly

@TuongNguyenMinh the $u$ variables measure how much $f$ is “to the right and above” your ideal point and the $l$-variables measure how much $f$ is “to the left and below” the ideal point.

Thank you so much ! Would you kindly give me some reference on this $l, u$ goal programming style ? It is so novel and attractive to me. I think your goal programming solution is the best solution in this case. Especially on the just trying to meet some goal aspect instead of having to meet exactly.
